# How to convert time from JavaScript correctly in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I have a time array like

```
[2023,1,3,17,0,0]
```

When I use Date.UTC in javascript, It produces the right result

My code

```
const utcDate1 = new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 1, 3, 17,0,0));
console.log(utcDate1.toUTCString());
```

result:

```
"Fri, 03 Feb 2023 17:00:00 GMT"
```

How to get the same result in php like javascript?
I tried with `mktime` in php but the return result is not what i expected. It differs by one month.

my php code:

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", mktime(17,0,0,1,3,2023));
```

result by PHP :

```
03-01-2023 17:00:00
```

Comment: Do you mean to implement this code in php?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything or done any research?

Comment: i tried with mktime in php but the return result is not what i expected it to be different when using date.Utc in java script

Comment: You need to [edit] the question and show what you tried, then we can help you fix it, or rule it out as a solution. That shows you made an effort before asking for everyone's time, and also usually makes it faster to get to an answer. See also [ask]. Thanks

Comment: You need to show the specific code you tried and show the specific result you got. Otherwise it's pretty much meaningless

Comment: Yes, I done update question

Comment: yes , i done add it

Comment: So the problem is actually how to format the output of the date? Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and the linked articles to find out what characters you can use to control the date format

Comment: you seem to be misunderstanding me , do you see the difference between the months from the two results ?

Comment: `you seem to be misunderstanding me`...possibly I did, sorry. That was the most obvious difference. That's why you should always explain the **exact** problem you're having :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript** uses a date format that stores months **0 based**: month "0" means January.

**PHP** does not, php considers **January** to be **month 1**.

Thats why in js `Date.UTC(2023, 1, 3, 17,0,0)` represents February 3rd, but in php `mktime(17,0,0,1,3,2023)` represents January 3rd.

When using that js-style date input `[2023,1,3,17,0,0]` in php you'll have to +1 to the month value.

---

If that part of your system is under your control and you have the possibility to change the format you use to exchange date values between js and php, i'd highly recommend to use a format that both systems understand. E.g. ISO 8601 or unix timestamps.